# JTextField only shows absolute value and no negative sign?

Tags: java, swing, formatting, jtextfield, negative-number

I am working on a "bank account' type program, and my goal is to withdraw and deposit money, show the updated balance, show the account status (overdrawn or not). I just got the adding/subtracting and updating the balance working, however the numbers in my JTextFields are absolute values, and do not show a negative balance (balance < 0). Is there some sort of formatting I need to do? I've included my code for the button listeners as well as some of the parsing I did to convert the doubles to strings etc. Please help!

```
     depositButton.addActionListener(new DepositListener());
     withdrawButton.addActionListener(new WithdrawListener());

    //create object of BankAccount, assign values to the text fields
     BankAccount myAcct = new BankAccount(1524687, 100.00, "Landon Wiggs");
     acctNameF.setText(myAcct.getName() );
     acctNumF.setText(Integer.toString( myAcct.getAcctNumber() ) );
     acctBalanceF.setText( Double.toString(myAcct.getBalance()));
     depositWithdrawAmtF.setText("0.00");


  private class DepositListener implements ActionListener 
{
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
      {  
         double sum = Double.valueOf(depositWithdrawAmtF.getText()) + Double.valueOf(acctBalanceF.getText());
         double amt = (Double.parseDouble(depositWithdrawAmtF.getText()));
         acctBalanceF.setText(Double.toString(sum)); 
      }
   }

private class WithdrawListener implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
         double sum = (Double.valueOf(depositWithdrawAmtF.getText() )) - (Double.valueOf(acctBalanceF.getText() ));
         double amt = (Double.parseDouble(depositWithdrawAmtF.getText()));

         acctBalanceF.setText(Double.toString(sum));   
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you withdraw you probably should substract the withdrawal amount from the account money, now you are doing the opposite.

Change

```
double sum = (Double.valueOf(depositWithdrawAmtF.getText() )) - (Double.valueOf(acctBalanceF.getText() ));
```

to

```
double sum = Double.valueOf(acctBalanceF.getText()) - Double.valueOf(depositWithdrawAmtF.getText());
```

Comment: Ah I see what I did there. I actually copied and pasted from the deposit button listener. foolish mistake, thanks for your help!